# How to copy specific headers in Soong

Tags: android-source, android-soong

How can I extract specific files in Soong to use as headers?

I was recently writing a blueprint (`Android.bp`) file for paho-mqtt-c.  My consumers require `MQTTClient.h` which paho-mqtt-c stores in `src/` - what I would consider a "*private*" location.  Reading their `CMakeLists.txt` file, it actually installs this and some other headers to `include/`.

As far as I can tell, Soong doesn't have this concept of installing so it seems like I could `export_include_dirs` the `src` directory - which seems wrong, or use a `cc_genrule` to copy these headers elsewhere.

But that's where I hit another issue: I can't seem to figure out how to create a `cc_genrule` that takes `n` inputs and writes `n` outputs (`n-to-n`).  *i.e.*

```
cc_genrule {
   name: "paho_public_headers",
   cmd: "cp $(in) $(out)",

   srcs: [ "src/MQTTAsync.h",    "src/MQTTClient.h",    "src/MQTTClientPersistence.h",   "src/MQTTLogLevels.h" ]
   out:  [ "public/MQTTAsync.h", "public/MQTTClient.h", "public/MQTTClientPersistence.h", "public/MQTTLogLevels.h" ],
}
```

results in the failed command `cp <all-inputs> <all-outputs>`, rather than what I wanted which would be closer to iterating the command over each input/output pairs.

My solution was simply to write four `cc_genrule`s, but that doesn't seem great either.

Is there a better way? (ideally without writing a custom `tool`)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `gensrcs` with a `shard_size` of 1.

For example:

```
gensrcs {
    name: "paho_public_headers",
    cmd: "mkdir -p $(genDir) && cat $(in) > $(out)",
    srcs: [":paho_mqtt_c_header_files"],
    output_extension: "h",
    shard_size: 1,
    export_include_dirs: ["src"],
}
```

The `export_include_dirs` is important, as with `gensrcs` there is little control over the output filename other than the extension, so it's easiest to keep the directory structure `$(in)` on the `$(out)` files.